# angularjs: view data doesn't update after async call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am using a 3rd party js library to make http requests to their api. I perform this operation on every keystroke in an input field using "ng-keyup". After the call to there api returns I set the $scope.results which populates the view. However the view always updates one iteration behind, debugging this looks to be with the async call.

Is there a way to refresh the view or make the async call differently rather than just a callback?

Comment: Could we get some code?

Comment: I'm guessing the initial call doesn't run a digest cycle, causing everything after to be 1 step behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your callback might be executing outside of angular context. Try calling `$scope.$apply()` in async callback. If that's not the issue, post some code please :)