# $scope Doesn't Apply Change To View After Async Call to Third Party API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

I'm making an async call to a speech recognition API and try to store the result in a $scope variable, but the view doesn't change, even though the results show up in `console.log` just fine. I tried using `$scope.$apply()` and `$scope.applyAsync();` as suggested in these threads - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020350/angularjs-view-data-doesnt-update-after-async-call) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907903/angularjs-scope-not-updating-in-view-after-async-call), unfortunately with no effect

Here's what controller looks like:

```
myApp.controller('audiotest', function($scope)
                    {
    $scope.recognize = function(){
        speech.main('test.wav', function(err, res){
        $scope.myResult = res.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
        console.log($scope.myResult); // <- this logs correctly
        $scope.$applyAsync(); // also tried with $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
 };
```

I don't think the markup is relevant, but here it is, anyway:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="audiotest">
<div class="row">

   <button type="button" ng-click="recognize()"> Attempt recognition </button>

<p> Result is {{myResult}} </p>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any input or ideas.

Comment: Have you tried `$timeout(function(){ $scope.myResult = res.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript; }, 0)`?

Comment: How about moving scope operation to the apply function like so: `$scope.$applyAsync(function () { $scope.myResult = res.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript; });`

Comment: @Lenilson de Castro, I tried that with both the $apply and $applyAsync function, but it still does nothing.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle reproducing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try to initialize your myResult on scope before declaring recognize function.